# Definition of 'feature coverage'

Tags: feature-selection, terminology

I have heard the term *'feature coverage'* in machine learning. However I found no relative infomation after I googled this term. Could some one give me a definition of *'feature coverage'* and some references?

Comment: Would be lovely if you could at least tell us where you heard this. To my opinion, feature coverage could represent the ability of some build features to cover the information contained in your initial data.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context it may mean differently. One common usage of the term is when not all the data points have valid/reliable values for a specific feature. For example for a feature set of $x=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p, \dots, x_n\}$ not all data points may have specific feature $p$.

It is possible that some data points lack a value for feature $p$ either because of data corruption, noise or etc. In this case the percentage of data point which actually have a reliable value for this feature is called the feature coverage of feature $p$ for this specific data set.

Comment: Thank you, is there any reference I can read?